# nginx + php5-fpm graceful restart : reload on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, ubuntu-14.04

I tried to find a way to gracvelly restart my server.

I tried `sudo service php5-fpm reload && sudo service nginx reload`

But this is not working as reloading php5-fpm on Ubuntu 14.04 is not working properly (The php5-fpm instance is showed as unknown)

After executing the previously command I got

```
sudo service php5-fpm status
> php5-fpm stop/waiting
sudo service php5-fpm restart
> stop: Unknown instance: 
> php5-fpm start/running, process 26042
sudo service php5-fpm restart
> stop: Unknown instance: 
> php5-fpm start/running, process 26141
```

The only way I found to restart php5-fpm after that is to run:

```
sudo killall php5-fpm
sudo service php5-fpm start
> php5-fpm start/running, process 26160
```

Thank You,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this one was killing me and all my coworkers too :)
Here's the solution:
Edit the file:

> /etc/init/php5-fpm.conf

and uncomment the line containing (it's line 13 on my box):

> reload signal USR2

Then kill all the php-fpms:

find their process ids:

> ps aux | grep php-fpm

kill them:

> sudo kill [proc-id]

And voila your "sudo service php5-fpm restart" is working again